# How to store multiple items in firebase using push()

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the following to be inserted into firebase but read that we can only store one information at a time? I thought that we can somehow store multiple information under a single unique id? Below is the code and I am trying to insert information such as phone numbers, address etc. With the address, can we use a string for the whole address or must we break it down to integer plus string? Also, should i be using "long" for phone number? I am also not sure if I should be using multiple Firebasedatabase for this?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button logout;
    private EditText edit;
    private EditText number;
    private EditText address;
    private EditText phone;
    private EditText postcode;
    private Button add;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        edit = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        add = findViewById(R.id.add);
        number = findViewById(R.id.number);
        address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        postcode = findViewById(R.id.postcode);


        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
                finish();
            }

        });

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void  onClick(View v) {
                String txt_name = edit.getText().toString();
            //    int txtnumber = Integer.valueof(number);
                String txt_address = address.getText().toString();
        //        Long phone_number = Long.parseLong(phone.getText().toString().trim());
        //        Long postcode2 = Long.parseLong(postcode.getText().toString().trim());



                if (txt_name.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No name entered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinic").push().child("Name").setValue(txt_name, txt_address);
               //     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinic").setValue(txt_address);
               //     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinic").child("Name:").child("Address No:").child("Address Name:").setValue(txt_address);
                //    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinic").child("Name:").child("Address No:").child("Address Name").child("Phone number:").setValue(phone_number);
                //    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinic").child("Name:").child("Address No:").child("Address Name").child("Phone number:").child("Postcode:").setValue(postcode2);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: I can get it to work with hashmap but is it possible to get it to work with that code that I have initially?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class named Info

```
 public class Info {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String postcode;

    public Info(String name, String address, String phoneNo, String postcode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public Info() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }
}
```

then in your activity

```
     add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void  onClick(View v) {
                String txt_name = edit.getText().toString();
            //    int txtnumber = Integer.valueof(number);
                String txt_address = address.getText().toString();
        //        Long phone_number = Long.parseLong(phone.getText().toString().trim());
        //        Long postcode2 = Long.parseLong(postcode.getText().toString().trim());



                if (txt_name.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No name entered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinic").push().getKey();
Info info = new Info(name,String.valueOf(txtnumber),String.valueOf(phone_number),String.valueOf(postcode2));
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child(key).setValue(info);

 
        });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222185/discussion-on-answer-by-wahdat-kashmiri-how-to-store-multiple-items-in-firebase).